# Error in setInternet2(TRUE) : use != NA is defunct

Tags: r

Since I upgraded to R Version 3.3.1, when I try and exit from R using q(), I get the following message: "Error in setInternet2(TRUE) : use != NA is defunct"

This happens on every exit.

I haven't used setInternet2 and it is not in .Rprofile, or .Rprofile.site.
I do not have a .Renviron.site file.

I checked I had the right setup files using:

```
file.path(getwd(),".Rprofile")
file.path(getwd(),".Rprofile.Site")
file.path(getwd(),".Renviron.site")
```

I'm using R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21) and Windows 7 x64 Service Pack 1

Comment: What is the content of your Rprofile files?

Comment: Possibly a function has the above check wrapped in call to  `on.exit`, you can confirm if this is the case with `mvbutils::callees.of("on.exit")`

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a late reply, but for the record:

This happened because

> as of R 3.3.0, setInternet2 is now defunct. Use of setInternet2 should be replaced with the method = "wininet" argument to the url and download.file functions

So it's not like anything else got changed or added, just before this wouldn't have caused such a message.

To know where it stems from is maybe not that easy, it could also be that you had in the past set it and saved your workspace and never cleaned your workspace completely afterwards.